# Complete and correct version of Siddha Kunjika Stotra

Tags: scripture, stotra, kali, durga-saptasati, chamunda

Can anyone please help with the complete and correct version of Siddha Kunjika stotra from Rudrayamala Tantra. In famous publications like Geeta press, complete version is not given. This is the version which I have. [image: Siddha Kunjika part 1][image: Siddha Kunjika part 2]

Comment: Humble request to help in this question. Please don't assume that i wanted to accomplish bad things with this stotra. Devi is intelligent enough to understand who is bad or good devotee.

Comment: Have you looked into sanskrit documents?- it lists variations as var: https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/siddhakunjikaa.html

Comment: @Proxy sir isn't Siddha Kunjika Stotram complete already? What is the proof that it's incomplete?

Comment: No need for 'sir'. I didn't understood the comment. I was just focusing on the variation in verses as listed by sanskrit documents, for e.g. in 5th verse the mantra starts with ॐ ऐं... while the variation (as signified by 'var') starts with श्रुँ श्रुँ...

Comment: @Ram Welcome back! ... Why did you write this comment "Humble request to help in this question. Please don't assume .."? No need of clarifying anything. You can delete that comment. BTW what made you think the version of the stotra you have is incomplete?

Comment: @Rickross Some devi bhakts take responsibility on themselves of protecting stotra without even devi wanted to them. So for them I have commented this. In some books like Gita press Saptashati, lines are missing so this question.

Comment: @Proxy: Yes I have already checked Sanskritdocuments. Com and if you check the Gita Press Saptashati some lines are missing. So I have asked this question.

Comment: @Rickross if you could resolve the above question that would be great buddy

Comment: @Ram I have the complete stotra, have you got any personal handle? So, I cqn share there?  (PS- Im not saying everyone here has something evil on mind, yet even by slighest chance undeserving person gets that, it's havoc. Kindly don't take other wise.)

Comment: @Chamundadas let's chat in some chat room so that i can share email id

Comment: @Ram Sure, will be much pleased, can u please give the link to Chat room. Or maybe u need to create one for this prolly.

Comment: @Chamundadas come to hinduism room

Comment: @ram already there sir.